# JSON parse error Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to decode a json object:

Code:

```
    public class retData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    private void btnCreateProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jsonResponse = Helpers.translateText("Some {useful|helpful|beneficial|valuable|handy|practical} {tips|suggestions|ideas|guidelines|recommendations|strategies} for {getting|obtaining|acquiring|receiving|finding|having} {best|very best|greatest|ideal|finest|most effective} and {professional|expert|skilled|specialist|qualified|experienced} carpet {cleaning|cleansing} {services|solutions|providers|companies|expert services|products and services}%first_paragraph-article%Some {useful|helpful|beneficial|valuable|handy|practical} {tips|suggestions|ideas|guidelines|recommendations|strategies} for {getting|obtaining|acquiring|receiving|finding|having} {best|very best|greatest|ideal|finest|most effective} and {professional|expert|skilled|specialist|qualified|experienced} carpet {cleaning|cleansing} {services|solutions|providers|companies|expert services|products and services}", "de", txtBoxYandexAPI.Text);
        retData theText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<retData>(jsonResponse);
    }
```

The response JSON is:

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-de","text":["Einige {nützlich|hilfreich|nützlich|wertvoll|nützlich|praktisch} {Tipps|Vorschläge|Ideen|Leitlinien|Empfehlungen|Strategien} {Anreise|Beschaffung|Erwerb|erhalten|finden|haben} {besten|besten|größten|ideal|besten|meisten effektive} und {professional|expert|qualifizierten|Spezialisten|qualifizierte|erfahrene} Teppich {Reinigung|cleansing} {Dienstleistungen|Lösungen|Dienstleister|Unternehmen|expert services|Produkte und Dienstleistungen} %first_paragraph-Artikel% Einige {nützlich|hilfreich|nützlich|wertvoll|nützlich|praktisch} {Tipps|Vorschläge|Ideen|Leitlinien|Empfehlungen|Strategien} {Anreise|Beschaffung|Erwerb|erhalten|finden|haben} {besten|besten|größten|ideal|besten|meisten effektive} und {professional|expert|qualifizierten|Spezialisten|qualifizierte|erfahrene} Teppich {Reinigung|cleansing} {Dienstleistungen|Lösungen|Dienstleister|Unternehmen|expert services|Produkte und Dienstleistungen} "]}
```

The error i'm getting is: **Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'text', line 1, position 35.** i'm using the newtonsoft json package, i don't see the issue, the JSON response looks correct to me or is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a `List<string>` for text as in your json, key contains array of string.
so it will look like

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            string jsonResponse = "{\"code\":200,\"lang\":\"en-de\",\"text\":[\"Einige {nützlich|hilfreich|nützlich|wertvoll|nützlich|praktisch} {Tipps|Vorschläge|Ideen|Leitlinien|Empfehlungen|Strategien} {Anreise|Beschaffung|Erwerb|erhalten|finden|haben} {besten|besten|größten|ideal|besten|meisten effektive} und {professional|expert|qualifizierten|Spezialisten|qualifizierte|erfahrene} Teppich {Reinigung|cleansing} {Dienstleistungen|Lösungen|Dienstleister|Unternehmen|expert services|Produkte und Dienstleistungen} %first_paragraph-Artikel% Einige {nützlich|hilfreich|nützlich|wertvoll|nützlich|praktisch} {Tipps|Vorschläge|Ideen|Leitlinien|Empfehlungen|Strategien} {Anreise|Beschaffung|Erwerb|erhalten|finden|haben} {besten|besten|größten|ideal|besten|meisten effektive} und {professional|expert|qualifizierten|Spezialisten|qualifizierte|erfahrene} Teppich {Reinigung|cleansing} {Dienstleistungen|Lösungen|Dienstleister|Unternehmen|expert services|Produkte und Dienstleistungen} \"]}";
            retData theText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<retData>(jsonResponse);
        }
        public class retData
        {
            public List<string> text { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as your `retdata` object:

```
public class retData
{
  public int code { get; set; }
  public string lang { get; set; }
  public List<string> text { get; set; }
}
```

the `text` is array of string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text property is an array with one component, so basically you will need to figure it out.

Basically you're looking into deserializing using the following class:

```
public class retData
{    
   public int code { get; set; }
   public string lang { get; set; }
   public string[] text { get; set; }
}
```

And after that you need to get `.FirstOrDefault()` or by index `[0]` from text property in order to grab that string.

P.S: if you don't use `code` and `lang`, you can leave them outside your `retData` class.